# Getting "TypeError: 'module' is not callable" when calculating execution time with timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I am trying to calculate the timings of my python code but I keep getting:

> TypeError - 'module' is not callable

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
```

The link I am checking is this - https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

I would expect to see the time that took the code to run.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in both python 2.75 and 3.6.8.

Comment: Check that you run exactly the code you've posted here.

Comment: I am using 3.6.8 as well, no idea what could be the reason to raise that error. Yes, I am using the exact code snippet as above.

Comment: It looks that you tried to execute "timeit()" instead of "timeit.timeit()"

Comment: your error is raised if you write only `timeit` instead of `timeit.timeit`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you perhaps name your file as *timeit.py*?

```
$ cat timeit.py
import timeit
timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)

$ python3 timeit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeit.py", line 1, in <module>
    import timeit
  File "/path/to/timeit.py", line 2, in <module>
    timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

You have to rename your file to something else (ex. *mytimeit.py*).
Otherwise `import` will import *your* `timeit` instead of the *real* `timeit` module.

You can check the `import`-ed module with `print(timeit.__file__)`.

```
$ cat timeit.py
import timeit
print(timeit.__file__)

timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)

$ pwd
/work/scratch

$ python timeit.py
/work/scratch/timeit.py
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

Also, if you want to see "*the time that took the code to run*", you have to print it.

```
$ mv timeit.py mytimeit.py
$ cat mytimeit.py
import timeit
print(timeit.__file__)
print(timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000))

$ python3 mytimeit.py 
/usr/lib/python3.6/timeit.py
0.1469665479962714
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Indeed I have named it timeit.py and the same issue was with stringio.py naming - will note that in to future, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting furious as my script worked just fine whenever I ran it in Spyder but not when I called it via `python timeit.py` from the command line. Guess that's a life lesson to never ever give a file the same name as a module.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go!

`import time`

`origin_time = time.time()` with this you will get the current time in seconds from the epoch

And whenever you want to know the time spent, just write:

`current_spent_time = time.time() - origin_time`this will get again the current time (in seconds) and substracts the previous origin_time which was the time when your code start running.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, so I would call origin_time in the first line after all of the import section, and call current_spent_time after specific code parts to get the time spent, neat. But I want to use the timeit library to check the time it took to run program 10,000 times.

Comment: What about `for i in range(10000)`and then append the time to a list and after sum(list)/10000